# Bootstrap Pagination Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to use the bootstrap pagination plugin but I am a little lost as to how I can display content using this feature. The code will display "page" followed by the page number. Can anyone tell me how to add text in paragraphs? Please see the code below:

```
<p id="content"></p>
<p id="pagination-here"></p>

<script>
$('#pagination-here').bootpag({
    total: 7, // total pages 
    page: 1, // default page 
    maxVisible: 5, // visible pagination 
    leaps: true // next/prev leaps through maxVisible 
}).on("page", function(event, num) {
    $("#content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading... 
    // ... after content load -> change total to 10 
    $(this).bootpag({
        total: 10,
        maxVisible: 10
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can advise u bootgrid.It is easier

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: HI John!! How are you? I will remember to be a complete robot next time John. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this....

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pagination&stacked=h
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-default

Thanks

Comment: Hi User, I am given for Bootstrap css pagination have a look for idea.